# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in Class.forName

Tags: java

[image]

I attached my code here. I tried to get object with the `newInstance` method. And it's showing that `ClassNotFound exception`.

Comment: 1. [Don't post images of code.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) 2. You need to pass the fully qualified class name, e.g., `com.TestAbc.abc`.

Answer (score 0):

Yo have to include package name with your class to create a new instance of abc class like below also you have to throws few exceptions as well which i have mentioned in below example.

```
public class TestCircle {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException{
        Class.forName("yourPackageName.abc").newInstance();

    }
 }

class abc {
    static
          {
            System.out.println("Executed static block");
          } {
            System.out.println("Executed Object");
        }
}
```